# More than two table using joins

Tags: sql, join

**MainTable**

```
ID Column1         TableA.fK TableB.fk
1  some-value        1          null
2  some-value        1          1
3  some-value        null       2
```

**TableA**

```
TableA.pk  Column1
1          some-value
```

**TableB**

```
TableB.pk Column1
1         some-value
2         some-value
```

```sql
Select  Main.ID,Main.Column1 ,A.Column1,B.Column1
FROM    MainTable main
LEFT JOIN
        Table A
ON      Main.TableA.fk = A.TableA.pk
LEFT JOIN
        TableB b
ON      Main.TableB.fk =B.TableB.fk
WHERE   Main.ID =1
```

Means

**The Result is**

```
  ID  Column1     A.Column1  B.Column1
  1   some-value   some-value  null
```

**Expecting Output**

```
 ID    column1         A.Column1
 1     some-value     some-value
```

**should not display B.column1**

when tableA foreign key value has not null, it should get all details from TableA if above SELECT query used here
im using RDBMS Microsoft Sql Server 2008

Comment: If you are expecting only `ID` and `A.Column1`, why you include `B.Column1` into your `SELECT` ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I don't understand the problem here. If you don't want it to display `B.Column1`, take `B.Column1` out of your `Select` statement.</strike>

<strike>You now have</strike>

<strike>Select Main.ID, A.Column1, B.Column1</strike>

<strike>Change it to</strike>

<strike>Select Main.ID, A.Column1</strike>

Based on your comments below, it seems like you're looking for `Coalesce` or `IsNull`, depending on which DBMS you're using (which you didn't tell us in your question either).

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT  
  Main.ID, Coalesce(A.Column1, B.Column1) as Column1
FROM    
  MainTable main
LEFT JOIN
  Table A
ON      
  Main.TableA.fk = A.TableA.pk
LEFT JOIN
  TableB b
ON
  Main.TableB.fk = B.TableB.fk
WHERE   
  Main.ID = 1
```

Comment: this is the original question (*which is already deleted*) [Link Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697307/how-to-use-coalesce). The op wants to project only the *non-null* columns. So basically my suggestion for the OP is to use *dynamic sql*.

Comment: i need both table if both table's foreign key is not null

Comment: @JW: Ah, yep. That knowledge does change things considerably. I'll delete this answer. Thanks for the heads up. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite delete it later `:)` others may need to see this as well `:D`

Comment: @AshokRavi: You need to edit your question to provide more info. What it says now is not what you just said in your comment.

Comment: sorry for my bad english ....i mean its case statement **if tableA foreign key have not null value in maintable  ,then select query should get all details from tableA** or is null  means skip from there

Comment: @Ashok: I mean **[edit] your question to provide that information**. Don't put it here where people can't see it.

Comment: @J W How to use dynamic sql to this output

Comment: @AshokRavi: Please **stop** having a conversation in the comments. This is **not** a chat room or discussion group. Please read the [faq] if you're not sure how StackOverflow works. And for the last time, **[edit] your question!!**

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put this column into the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT  Main.ID, A.Column1
FROM    MainTable main
LEFT JOIN
        Table A
ON      Main.TableA.fk = A.TableA.pk
LEFT JOIN
        TableB b
ON      Main.TableB.fk = B.TableB.fk
WHERE   Main.ID = 1
```

Comment: this is the original question (*which is already deleted*) [Link Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697307/how-to-use-coalesce). The op wants to project only the *non-null* columns. So basically my suggestion for the OP is to use *dynamic sql*.

Answer (score 0):

Remove B.Column1 from your query

```
Select Main.ID,A.Column1 FROM MainTable main LEFT JOIN Table A ON Main.TableA.fk=A.TableA.pk LEFT JOIN TableB b ON Main.TableB.fk =B.TableB.fk WHERE Main.ID =1
```